# Texmaker: how to auto-complete any environment?

Tags: texmaker, auto-completion

Is there a way to get Texmaker to auto-complete any environment? I would like it to insert an `\end{...}` line for every `\begin{...}` line I write, regardless of the particular environment I opened. It seems to only do this with environments it recognizes (e.g. `equation`, `align` etc., but not self-defined environments).

Comment: you can add your environments to autocomplete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to switch to Texmaker's fork TeXstudio which has got this feature built-in. http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I tried it out - seems to be the best option. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Texmaker allows you to insert your own tags (shortcuts : <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, ..., <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>). These tags are defined with the "User - User Tags" menu.
Notes :

If the code of the menu is "%environment", Texmaker will directly insert:

```
\begin{environment }
•
\end{environment }
```

and the cursor will jump directly to the "•" field.

http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html